# Migration from Icefaces 1.8 to 4.2

Tags: jsf-2, migration, icefaces

I am migrating an old application from Icefaces 1.8 to Icefaces 4.2. I am getting numerous compilation issues as following component classes are no longer available:

1. HtmlCommandLink (com.icesoft.faces.component.ext.HtmlCommandLink)
2. HtmlGraphicImage (com.icesoft.faces.component.ext.HtmlGraphicImage)
3. HtmlOutputLabel (com.icesoft.faces.component.ext.HtmlOutputLabel)
4. HtmlOutputLink (com.icesoft.faces.component.ext.HtmlOutputLink)
5. HtmlOutputText(com.icesoft.faces.component.ext.HtmlOutputText)
6. HtmlPanelGrid (com.icesoft.faces.component.ext.HtmlPanelGrid)
7. HtmlPanelGroup (com.icesoft.faces.component.ext.HtmlPanelGroup)
8. MenuBar (com.icesoft.faces.component.menubar.MenuBar)
9. com.icesoft.faces.component.IceExtended
10. com.icesoft.faces.component.paneltabset.TabChangeEvent
11. com.icesoft.faces.component.ext.taglib.Util
12. com.icesoft.faces.context.effects.JavascriptContext (includeLib)
13. com.icesoft.faces.component.DisplayEvent
14. com.icesoft.faces.component.ext.RowSelectorEvent

This is just a small list of elements which are no longer available in icefaces 4. I have lot more other elements as well.

So, the question is, where I can get the list of java implementation of the new components in icefaces 4 which will be substitute for the old Icefaces components?

Please note that I am not using html tag directly inside the xhtml page. I am just using the parent tag and pushing all the rest of the components on the page through java.

```
<f:view xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:ice="http://www.icesoft.com/icefaces/component"
    contentType="text/html">  

   <ice:portlet styleClass="box1">
        <ice:panelGroup styleClass="testPanelGroup"> 
           <ice:outputText value="#{test.Load}" visible="false"/>
           <ice:panelGroup binding="#{table.view}"/>
        </ice:panelGroup>
   </ice:portlet>
</f:view>
```

My sample java file where i am overriding the java implemenetaion of these tags an then using them in my code

```
public class HtmlGraphicImage extends
    com.icesoft.faces.component.ext.HtmlGraphicImage {

    @Override
    public Object getValue()
    {

   Object o = super.getValue();
   if (o == null || String.valueOf(o).isEmpty())
       return "/images/clear.gif";

   return o;
  }
}
}
```

I got the list of the updated components but not their Java implementation.

http://www.icesoft.org/wiki/display/ICE/ICE+to+ACE+Component+Migration+Guide

Comment: In think you need to try to find the sources of the intermediate versions and start comparing.

Comment: I was trying the same. I read the release notes of all the intermediate releases. Although I found some replacements (not included in above list) but icefaces 4.2 examples are very limited on web and are mostly based on xhtml icefaces component. I was looking for examples of replacement of old icefaces java components (mentioned above) with latest icefaces 4.2 java components implementation.

Comment: Did you ever find any solution to this ? i am in charge of an old app migration but i cannot find the replacement / alternative for IceUserObject